# directly accessing attribute of object when object is part of array

Tags: java, arrays, object, attributes

1. I defined "class Product" with fields "price" and "sales".
2. Then, I created an array of type "Product":
    Product productArray[] = new Product[100]
3. Then I filled this array with data from an excel table containing 100 rows and       2 columns (column A: "price" , column B: "sales")

I want to directly access the price of different products, say the price of the product in row 97.
That is, I would like to do something like 
Double variable = productArray[97].price

Is there a way of doing this in java ?

Help would be very much appreciated !
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, have you tried `Double variable = productArray[97].price`? Sounds like it should work. Maybe `productArray[97].getPrice()`? Also, beware that array are 0 indexed: row 1 is `productArray[0]`.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work if price has the right access modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create getter and setter methods for your variables as encapsulation is a good OOP concept to protect your variables.

Consider the following scenario which will be similar to what you are doing, you have a Product class.

I will use an alien class:

```
public class Alien{

//Properties of aliens
int numOfFingers;
String name;
String color;

public Alien(int num, String name, String color)
{
    this.numOfFingers = num;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
}       

}//End of alien class
```

The class containing the array:

```
public class DetailExtractor {

//Arraycontaining alien objects
Alien[] alienRegister = new Alien[100];

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Populating the array
    alienRegister[0] = new Alien(3, "Zorg", "Blue");
    alienRegister[1] = new Alien(5, "Chad", "Purple");


    //Retrieving a property, say name of second alien...

    System.out.println(alienRegister[1].name);

}

}
```

Comment: so my code should actually work ... then it didn't compile because of some other issue ... I thought it didn't work because of the "productArray[97].price"-part.